# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade

Tags: java, jsf, serialization

When I deploy my webapp, I see this error message

```
com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/qtl.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
...
```

I research around and this error might be because I try to serialize attribute that non-serializable. So I have an `ApplicationScoped` managed bean that look like below

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationBean implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, HttpSession> logins; 
    ...
}
```

Can `Map<String, HttpSession> logins` be Serializable?

**Tomcat 7**

Comment: Maps are normally serializable, but looks like the session implementation (org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade) is not. I can't imagine that its a good idea to serialize your session in this manner anyway.

Comment: check this out:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/httpsession_performance_serialization.html

Comment: @Perception: I need to know the `HttpSession` associated with a particular `userId` on my server, so when I delete them off my database, I can obtain their `HttpSession` back via their `userId`, and invalidate their sesssion. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @HarryPham - each user is explicitly tied to a session on your server (once that session is established). So you should be able to obtain the users session ***during*** the delete request, and invalidate it once the request is complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpSession` is indeed not serializable. The application scoped bean should also not be serializable after all. Remove the `implements Serializable` from the application scoped bean class and don't inject it as managed property of a session or view scoped bean. Instead, inject it in a request scoped bean only or grab it from the application map.

Comment: Sorry for taking a while to reply back to you. Since I am not inject my `ApplicationScoped` bean into my `SessionScoped` bean, now my `ApplicationScoped` bean is not even loaded. Is there a way to tell my `ApplicationScoped` bean to load first, BalusC?

Comment: Set `@ManagedBean(eager=true)` (or make the whole thing a `@WebListener` instead which implements `ServletContextListener` as well).